# How do I reset my SVN password in Netbeans?

Tags: svn, netbeans

My Subversion password changed.  In Netbeans, it always submits the old one.  When the Authentican failed screen comes up, I enter my new password and leave the "Save Username and Password" box checked.  However, the next time I need to do something, it still gives me the authentication failed message.

How do I get it to forget the old password and remember the new one?

Answer (score 4):

You can go to **`Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Versioning -> Subversion`** and set your new password there (maybe it helps to remove the url from history?).

But a better way to reset your connection is to remove the connections config file. To do this:

1. go to **`<application data>/NetBeans/7.3/config/svn/config/auth/svn.simple`**
2. See what file is the one of your connection (you can open the files with a text editor and check the urls)
3. Remove it and restart netbeans

Comment: The directory is also listed in **Help -> About** (User Directory).

Comment: Found under `Tools -> Options -> *Team* -> Versioning -> Subversion -> Manage Connection Settings` on my Apache Netbeans v12.2